# Where is the link to Meta from the profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page

As we already know, previously we had a link on Stack Overflow's main profile page, which redirects us to Meta Stack Overflow. Today I noticed that the button is missing:

[image]

I think this could cause less engagement in Meta Stack Overflow because people normally used to move here and there simply using the link without typing the entire URL.

Comment: It's not missing. Click on "Profiles" which will open a dropdown menu.

Comment: The whole layout of profiles has changed. I think if you click on "Profiles" you'll see an option to go to your meta profile.

Comment: This is their secret plan :) Engagement with Meta will drop and then Aaron will remove the links completely because less than 0.015% use Meta. On a more serious note, see Jeanne's comment - it's still there, just tucked under the dropdown.

Comment: MSE: [We’ve shipped some changes to the user profile navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369276/we-ve-shipped-some-changes-to-the-user-profile-navigation)

Comment: @JeanneDark Oh didn't notice that. However, I think it's better to keep this question posted because other users also might facing the same issue.

Comment: The *"NETWORK PROFILE"* link has been moved to "Profiles" as well. Now it is *"Network profile"*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the update. However, I still feel this dropdown is not that  user friendly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were some profile design changes made, [announced on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369276/571958). As part of these changes, there's a new "Profiles" dropdown menu in the upper right corner of the profile.  Click that, then click "Meta user".

[image: screenshot of profile with red arrows pointing to "Profiles" and "Meta user"]

If you just want to get to the front page of Meta quickly, though, just click the Stack Exchange logo in the upper right of any page, and there's an option to go to the current site's meta.

[image: Screenshot of upper right of page with red arrows pointing to the Stack Exchange logo and to the Meta Stack Overflow link]